# Display fields in seperate sections in EditFrame With Glass BeginEditFrame

Tags: experience-editor, glass-mapper

I am using Glass mapper BeginEditFrame functionality to generate EditFrames in Experience Editor mode.

In the Experience Editor mode, we need to divide and display Fields in sections (like "section" you can see in Content Editor for item).

If any idea on achieving this would be great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it's impossible (or at least from what I know ;) ). While defining which fields can be edited using the original Sitecore (non Glass) Edit Frame, you only specify pipe-separated list of field names:

[image]

Glass uses the same mechanisms. So if you want to split those fields into section, you would need to change the logic of how Sitecore handles edit frames and from what I see there is no easy place to hook into.

Comment: I would probably look into this: http://zablo.net/blog/post/sitecore-dynamic-field-editor - and then add something like a SectionDescriptor (if possible) in the ProvideDynamicFields method.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the

```
<command name="webedit:fieldeditor" type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.FieldEditor, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" patch:source="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.config"/>
```

with your implementation. You can have look how Sitecore rendering this out in `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.FieldEditor` class. But ash Marek Musielak mentioned above OOTB it is not possible.

Looks like that you need to overwrite the `GetOptions(ClientPipelineArgs args, NameValueCollection form)` method.